# org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN - Unable to proxy method

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, cglib

My web project deployed in tomcat and appears some warnings what about spring and hibernate proxy on final method, what has caused this problem?

```
2017-09-08 16:01:32,548 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getSessionFactory()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:32,548 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:32,548 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:32,548 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.setHibernateTemplate(org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:32,548 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet() throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException,org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:32,995 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getSessionFactory()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:32,995 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:32,995 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:32,995 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.setHibernateTemplate(org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:32,995 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet() throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException,org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:33,049 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getSessionFactory()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:33,049 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:33,049 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:33,049 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.setHibernateTemplate(org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:33,049 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet() throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException,org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:33,112 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getSessionFactory()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:33,112 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:33,112 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:33,113 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.setHibernateTemplate(org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:33,113 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet() throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException,org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:35,073 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getSessionFactory()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:35,073 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:35,073 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:35,073 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.setHibernateTemplate(org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:35,073 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet() throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException,org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:35,678 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getSessionFactory()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:35,678 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:35,678 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:35,679 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.setHibernateTemplate(org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:35,679 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet() throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException,org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:35,700 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getSessionFactory()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:35,700 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:35,700 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:35,700 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.setHibernateTemplate(org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
2017-09-08 16:01:35,700 org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet() throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException,org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will be routed directly to the proxy.
```

Comment: There is no problem and you can ignore these warnings. They are probably caused by the fact you enabled AOP and have a point cut which matches each and every class/bean in your context.

Comment: @M.Deinum For why? Why spring proxy a final method in hibernate ?

Comment: Because you enabled something that matches everything.

Comment: Can you find the way to disappear it ?

Comment: No... That is up to you. You wrote an aspect / point cut expression that leads to proxy creation of all the beans.

Comment: @M.Deinum `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />` I just add this.

Comment: Why would you add that if you don't have aspects... You have an aspect with a point cut that matches that bean.

Comment: @M.Deinum I need aspects in my project.

Comment: Where did I say you cannot use aspects... I only stated that you have an aspect with a point cut that matches those spring classes.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

See here.
[Spring boot - Unable to proxy interface-implementing method - WARN message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49339820/spring-boot-unable-to-proxy-interface-implementing-method-warn-message)

One of the common causes of this is using Springs @Transactional annotation at the class level rather than the interface.