# Spring boot - Unable to proxy interface-implementing method - WARN message

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cglib

From Spring boot 1.5.x, I receive the following WARN messages:

```
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.0.RELEASE)

2018-03-17 18:58:18.546  WARN 27877 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.a.f.CglibAopProxy                    : Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.setServletContext(javax.servlet.ServletContext)] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
2018-03-17 18:58:18.551  WARN 27877 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.a.f.CglibAopProxy                    : Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext) throws org.springframework.beans.BeansException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
2018-03-17 18:58:18.937  WARN 27877 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.a.f.CglibAopProxy                    : Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.setServletContext(javax.servlet.ServletContext)] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
2018-03-17 18:58:18.938  WARN 27877 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.a.f.CglibAopProxy                    : Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext) throws org.springframework.beans.BeansException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
2018-03-17 18:58:19.034  WARN 27877 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.a.f.CglibAopProxy                    : Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.setServletContext(javax.servlet.ServletContext)] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
2018-03-17 18:58:19.035  WARN 27877 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.a.f.CglibAopProxy                    : Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext) throws org.springframework.beans.BeansException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
2018-03-17 18:58:19.136  WARN 27877 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.a.f.CglibAopProxy                    : Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.setServletContext(javax.servlet.ServletContext)] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
2018-03-17 18:58:19.136  WARN 27877 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.a.f.CglibAopProxy                    : Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext) throws org.springframework.beans.BeansException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
```

I don't have CGLIB in the dependency hierarchy. I'm using only interfaces for DI and I've tried to disable `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)` and everything related to it, but still no change. (I've read that MethodSecurity and `@Secured` annotations in the Controller Classes can cause this WARNing, but it seems that I get them from another place.
How to know from where I receive these warnings?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with some @Transactional annotations on a Class level. After I put them on the interfaces (Repositories - I'm using spring data) Everything is OK :)

Answer (score 2):

After checking `@Transactional` annotation, make sure u put your `@Repository` annotation directly to **repository interface**. In my case I did the following:

1. Removed `@Transactional` and `@Repository` from my **DAO class**
2. Put `@Repository` to my repo interface
3. Put `@Component` to my **DAO class**

See [Spring Boot + Annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49339820/spring-boot-unable-to-proxy-interface-implementing-method-warn-message) for more info about annotations

Answer (score 0):

Based on the reported issue, I have faced same issue like having interface-implementing method with final.

From the concrete class (Bean) if we remove final from method , also solved the same issue.

Ref:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8974